# How to Make Float Not Move when Window is Resized

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have a header, a navbar, and content box as such (picture 1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/duM06.jpg

(Click next/previous to see both pictures)

I want two side-bars, one on the left, with pictures or something, and one on the right with an 'About Us' topic.

So I added them (picture 2).

Anyway, right now, if I resize the browser window the two sidebars overlap the content on the page; other than just staying put and not matching to fit the width of the page, like I would like them to do.

Code...

CSS:

```
#leftSide
{
height: 700px;
width: 425px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 35px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px #acacac;
position: relative;
float: left;
clear: left;
background-color: #FFF;
}

#rightSide
{

height: 700px;
width: 425px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-right: 35px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px #acacac;
position: relative;
float: right;
clear: right;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <a href="index.html"><h1>Heritage Bulk Organics</h1></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="product.html">Our Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>              
        </ul>   
    </div>

    <div id="leftSide">

    </div>

    <div id="rightSide">

    </div>

    <div class="paragraphBody">
                    //CONTENT//

        </p>        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple to solve. You just need to wrap everything in a container.

If you want the sidebars to always stay like they are, close to the content, then give the container a fixed width. This will introduce a horizontal scrollbar, but that's better than overlapping.

If you want the sidebars to stay next to the edge of the screen, but not overlap, then use a min-width. This will keep them next to the edge of the screen, as long as the screen is big enough, and should it become to small, then again, the horizontal scrollbar scenario, which is, again, better than overlapping.

```
<div id="containAll">
<!-- All your other code here -->
</div>

#containAll {width:###px;}
/* OR */
#containAll {min-width:###px;}
```

Comment: Eh, yes. That fixes it. But then it may have compatibility issues with other screen/browser sizes; right?

Comment: @user3400029 it shouldn't. `width` and `min-width` are supported by all major browsers.

Comment: No for example: my screen size is massive, 2000 X 1600 something. Ok? So then on a computer with a screen size of, say, 1280 X 720, the elements may be all over the screen and messed up.

Comment: @user3400029 No, not if you contain them within a fixed width element. The worst that will happen is a vertical scrollbar.